# Hardware selection for NVIDIA Titan Xp

Tags: graphics-cards, power-supply, cooling

I am a research student and I received a NVIDIA Titan Xp graphics card from NVIDIA as a research grant. However, the IT department in my department says that the gpu is can not be put inside any of our existing systems. So, I have decided to buy a system myself. But I am confused about what should I buy since there are so many factors to consider for example cooling, power requirement. Also, since I am buying this myself I don't want to cross 1000 euro. Can you please provide me some suggestions. Please keep in mind that my focus is on high-performance computing, this system will not be used for any other purpose.
Also, this is my first question on this site and I have very limited knowledge of hardware, so if something is not right or require more information please let me know, don't downvote.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does the card come with pre-equipped air cooling (ie "are there fans on the card")? Also what are you looking for in the rest of the system? A lot of sequential CPU power? A lot of parallel CPU power? A lot of RAM? A lot of Storage?

Comment: @SEJPM I think the card has air cooling. The device I received looks exactly like the one in the picture at page 6 (http://www.nvidia.com/content/geforce-gtx/NVIDIA_TITAN_Xp_User_Guide.pdf). My focus is highly parallel computing.

Comment: Are you looking for a complete system, or are you wanting to build your own?

Comment: @Cfinley Either is fine.  Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This question is quite broad, as there are a lot of things that go into a custom PC. It would be better to ask multiple separate questions if you are intending on building a PC as this site is for recommending hardware to meet a specific task, not building a PC for a user.

Comment: OK, the user guide says that the only hard requirements are that you _need_ 8GB RAM (16 preferably) and that the PSU should at least supply 600W and offer a 6+8 pin power connector. These are actually quite moderate requirements, I'll see if I find the time to throw some components together (but in any case other answerers can use the above information!).

Comment: @EdwardNunn Thank you for your kind response. If you need information for a specific task, then I should tell you that I intend to speed-up some algorithms using the parallel computing power of GPU. I intend to use CUDA for the programming. let me know if this helps.

Comment: OK, I should imagine that pretty much any parts can be used for that task so I'll leave @SEJPM to come up with a parts list.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few key things you need to look out for:

- You need 8-16GB of RAM
- As the card draws 250W max and the rest of the system probably draws the same, you need a 600W+ PSU that has at least one 6 and one 8 pin power connector.
- Your case needs to fit a 10.5" long, double-height graphics card (which is a pretty standard size).

Anything else is essentially up to you.

Now I've picked a few parts (w/o OS, optical drives and peripherals, if you need them, this needs tweaking) as a generic recommendation satisfying the above constraints, highlights:

- an 8-core AMD Ryzen 7 processor
- a 128GB Samsung PCIe SSD
- an all-in-one water cooling system for easier cleaning

The part list:

```
PCPartPicker part list: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/FM9Hyf
Price breakdown by merchant: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/FM9Hyf/by_merchant/

CPU: AMD - Ryzen 7 1700X 3.4GHz 8-Core Processor  ($329.59 @ SuperBiiz) 
CPU Cooler: Corsair - H60 54.0 CFM Liquid CPU Cooler  ($54.99 @ Newegg) 
Motherboard: Gigabyte - GA-AB350-GAMING 3 ATX AM4 Motherboard  ($99.89 @ OutletPC) 
Memory: G.Skill - Ripjaws V Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR4-2666 Memory  ($111.99 @ Newegg) 
Storage: Samsung - 960 EVO 250GB M.2-2280 Solid State Drive  ($127.49 @ OutletPC) 
Storage: Western Digital - Caviar Blue 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive  ($46.88 @ OutletPC) 
Video Card: NVIDIA - Titan Xp 12GB Video Card 
Case: NZXT - S340 (Black) ATX Mid Tower Case  ($69.99 @ B&H) 
Power Supply: EVGA - SuperNOVA NEX 650W 80+ Gold Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply  ($89.89 @ OutletPC) 
Total: $930.71
Prices include shipping, taxes, and discounts when available
Generated by PCPartPicker 2017-08-19 10:20 EDT-0400
```